# AWS Batch : role for aws batch is not listed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am new to AWS Batch. I have created following role for AWS batch:

```
  "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service":  [
                "batch.amazonaws.com"
          ]
        },
        "Sid": ""
      }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
  }
```

And attached with policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "batch:*",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
            "ecs:DescribeClusters",
            "ecs:Describe*",
            "ecs:List*",
            "logs:Describe*",
            "logs:Get*",
            "logs:TestMetricFilter",
            "logs:FilterLogEvents",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:ListRoles"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

But the role is not listed when I am trying to create an AWS Batch. Kindly help me on what I might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up any confusion around the purpose of roles involved in AWS Batch; when creating the "Compute Environment" you must provide existing roles for the **Service Role** and the **Instance Role**. The default (in the docs) for these roles should be fine, and these roles are used for creating and destroying EC2 instances (among other things).

I think the role and policy you are referring to is the **Job Role** which you can define when creating your "Job Definition".

In order to attach the above policy to the "Job Definition" it must be linked to the **Job Role**. To (easily) create the **Job Role** use the AWS IAM web interface, and chose "Role -> AWS Service -> Elastic Container Service -> Elastic Container Service Task" in order for the role to inherit the correct attributes and allow it to be assigned to your Job Definition.